# nested json data Post method from front end don't hit back end post method

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
[{"Id":0,"BuyerId":2,"ExpressList":[{"ExpressId":2,"FOBSHANGHAI1":"1"}]}]
```

This data comes from front end. In 'ExpressList' there might be multiple data.
My back end view mode is

```
public class TafettaExpressViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BuyerId { get; set; }
        public List<ExpressViewDetails> ExpressList { get; set; }
    }
 public class ExpressViewDetails
    {
        public int ExpressId{ get; set; }
        public string FOBSHANGHAI1{ get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TafettaExpressViewModel>> PostTafetta(List<TafettaExpressViewModel> data)
        {
            return data.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Front End
component.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    var data = Object.assign({}, ...this.dataShow); //Data that I wants to send
    this.insertRecord(data)
  }
insertRecord(data) {
this.service.postTafetta(data).subscribe(
  res => {
         console.log(res);
        })}
```

service.ts

```
postTafetta(data){
  return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/Tafetta', data);
}
```

Comment: The action isn't being hit or the data isn't binded? include the code that posts the data to the action.

Comment: Does your json request really ends with " ? If Yes, then it's not a valid JSON format and you have to remove the ". Also you send "ExpressId" : 2 which is an INT value but you expect a string on the backend side.

Comment: @Popa Andrei actually not. It's typing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `[{"Id":0,"BuyerId":2,"ExpressList":[{"ExpressId":2,"FOBSHANGHAI1":"1"}]}]`

Based on your testing data that is an array, you can try to modify the backend code like below to receive and process it.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TafettaExpressViewModel>> PostTafetta([FromBody]List<TafettaExpressViewModel> data)
{
    return data.FirstOrDefault(); // to see the api hits or not
}
```

*ViewModel classes*

```
public class TafettaExpressViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public List<ExpressViewDetails> ExpressList { get; set; }
}

public class ExpressViewDetails
{
    public int ExpressId { get; set; }
    public string FOBSHANGHAI1 { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Hi! I've edit my post and add front end part also. Still it's showing  http://localhost:2900/api/Tafetta 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I've solved the problem finally. The problem occurs due to the data conversation into object.